How to load web articles into RAG LLM for embedding
I watched this tutorial (https://youtu.be/2TJxpyO3ei4) on setting up RAG (retrieval augmented generation) using LLMs (I used a local embedding model and a local model for queries). I want to be able to have a data folder where I can read the documents from HTML files (or more preferably links). I believe this website (https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/html/) goes through it but I don't know how to add this to my already existing code that loads the document.
Here is the code (that works correctly for PDFs, and now I want to add HTML files/links):
`
def load_documents():

   document_loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH)
   return document_loader.load()

`
I tried changing the document_loader to be equal to something that took from HTML, but then the Pdfs weren't working properly. Also I don't know how to get the links from online.
I'm fairly certain the answer involves this: loader = UnstructuredHTMLLoader("example_data/fake-content.html")

All you need to do is use a new loader. Just make sure you are using the latest API and have installed all the necessary third-party libraries.
from langchain_community.document_loaders.url import UnstructuredURLLoader
from langchain_community.document_loaders.pdf import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
from langchain_community.document_loaders.html import UnstructuredHTMLLoader

urls = [
   'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42'
]
url_loader = UnstructuredURLLoader(urls=urls)
url_documents = url_loader.load()

pdf_folder_path = '/path/to/pdfs'
pdf_loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(path=pdf_folder_path)
pdf_documents = pdf_loader.load()

html_file_paths = ['/path/to/test.html', '/path/to/test2.html']
html_documents = []
for html_file_path in html_file_paths:
    html_loader = UnstructuredHTMLLoader(file_path=html_file_path)
    html_documents.append(html_loader.load())


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
